# Inject/Load local images into current web page with Selenium 2

Tags: java, image, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium Java application which loads custom JavaScript with the [JavaScript executor](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.java?r=11967). In the same way i am able to load custom CSS to the current page. But i also want to be able to load custom local images which are referenced in the CSS. Is that possible?

Comment: You mean like in `<style>body { background-url: /whatever.jpg; }</style>`?  The browser ought to do that automatically when it processes the CSS.

Comment: I cannot use an URL because there is no webserver running. I have to somehow serialize the images or use the binary format to include them directly in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it myself. The parameters:

- `styleDefinitions` is a string with the css stylesheet definitions.
- `flatImageFolder` is a boolean value. If true, all local images with relative urls are taken from the `src/main/resources/images` folder. If false they have to be placed inside the folder in the appropriate subfolders.

The java code:

```
public class SeleniumTools {
    public function loadCSS(String styleDefinitions, Boolean flatImageFolder) {
        Pattern pattern;
        if(flatImageFolder) {
            pattern = Pattern.compile("url\\((?:.*?\\/)(.*?).(png|gif)\\)");
        } else {
            pattern = Pattern.compile("url\\(((?:.*?\\/).*?).(png|gif)\\)");
        }
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(styleDefinitions);
        StringBuffer styleDefinitionsWithInlineImageData = new StringBuffer();
        int lastMatchEndPosition = 0;
        while(matcher.find()) {
            String filename = matcher.group(1);
            String extension = matcher.group(2);
            lastMatchEndPosition = matcher.end();
            matcher.appendReplacement(styleDefinitionsWithInlineImageData, "url(" + convertImageToBinaryData(
                        SeleniumTools.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/" + filename + "." + extension), extension) + ")");
        }
        // add all definitions from the last match until the end of the stylesheet
        styleDefinitionsWithInlineImageData.append(styleDefinitions.substring(lastMatchEndPosition));
        String script = "jQuery('<style type=\"text/css\">" + styleDefinitionsWithInlineImageData.toString() + "</style>').appendTo('html > head');";
        ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(script);
    }

    private static String convertImageToBinaryData(InputStream imageInputStream, String fileExtension) {
        BufferedImage image;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(imageInputStream);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, fileExtension, baos);
            return "data:image/" + fileExtension + ";base64," + Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```